# Sound mutes when clicking on Recording tab in Sounds

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

**This is quite an urgent issue because I am working remotely.**

I can't get my mic and sound to work together on a Skype (or anything) call. As soon as I call someone, then all my pc sounds get muted/stop, and therefore I cannot hear the person talking. As soon as I end the call, then all the sounds come back.

Here is a possible answer to my question: [Why does clicking on the recording tab under sound preferences change my audio?](https://superuser.com/questions/1118960/why-does-clicking-on-the-recording-tab-under-sound-preferences-change-my-audio)

The above is probably the reason for the problem, but how do I know fix the problem?